# slither: command not found?

Tags: slither

I have installed slither using `pip3 install slither-analyzer`, but I get the error `slither: command not found` when I use `slither .`

ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS 
pip 20.0.2 
pyhton 3.8.10

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. In my case, the path where pip3 stored slither, $HOME/.local/bin/, wasn't in my $PATH environment variable.

After including this, problem solved.